# How to sort an array of elements based on the condition

Tags: javascript

I have an array of elements as

`let array = ["Approved", "Pending", "Not Approved", "Rejected", "Failed"]`

I have an Another array

```
let array1 = ["Approved", "Failed", "Pending", "Not Approved", "Pending", "Rejected", "Not Approved"]
```

I want to sort the array1 elements based on the order i have in array

Expected Output:

```
["Approved", "Pending",  "Pending", "Not Approved", "Not Approved", "Rejected", "Failed",]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Try like `array1.sort((a, b) => array.indexOf(a) - array.indexOf(b))` . But always make sure you add your try in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = ["Approved", "Pending", "Not Approved", "Rejected", "Failed"]
const array1 = ["Approved", "Failed", "Pending", "Not Approved", "Pending", "Rejected", "Not Approved"]

array1.sort((a, b) => array.indexOf(a) - array.indexOf(b))

console.log(array1)
```